# Can I replace a published vector layer with another one?

Tags: geoserver

I have published a vector layer of polygons in GeoServer.
Can I replace it, with the same WMS and WFS services, with a newer layer?  It is basically the same layer with added features.

Comment: Do you mean replace the data? Why not just reload the feature type properties?

Comment: Yes exactly. How can I do that?

Comment: Go to your layer, Data and scroll all the way down. just beneath the feature type details you can find the `Reload feature type` button.